# Using VLOOKUP in Excel keeps returning N/A error

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm admittedly new to using VLOOKUP in Excel, but I've run through a few tutorials on this and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I'm attaching a sample of the table I'm working with, where I'm attempting to match a value (ZPOP) that is dependent on another value (ZIPCODE). The formula I'm using is

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,M:N,2,TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: `VLOOKUP(--A2,M:N,2,TRUE)`. You have text-that-looks-like-a-number in column A.

Comment: Instead of `--A2` you can also use `INTEGER(A2)`, the latter converts something into an integer, exactly what you need to achieve.

Comment: A quick check with numbers/text as numbers is to look at the natural alignment of the number.  Aligned left as shown in column A of your screenshot means it's being read as text, right aligned as shown in column M of your screenshot means it's being read as a number - MATCH, VLOOKUP, etc must match numbers to numbers, text to text.

Answer (score 0):

When I do the same as you, it looks like the formula is exact.

But, there's one thing in your Excel sheet: there is a warning at the beginning of your A-column. In order to reproduce this, I've replaced the value `59001` by `'59001` (mind the single quote), and there the problem arises too.

Please check the warning of your A column and do some reformatting of that value, if possible.